# Is locking a mutex enough for writes outside of the mutex in one thread to update memory in a second thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Wanting to share a `std::vector` across threads and only locking a mutex to pass around an index. Basic idea below, the question is if the mutex is enough to make sure that the data written outside the lock in `thread1` is picked up in `thread2`. I know `fooFree` and `fooProcess` are fine (as they are updating under the lock) but seems to me that the compiler (and/or processor cache coherence) does not have to make sure `foo[index]`'s data is synchronized (as it is outside the lock).

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

constexpr size_t dataSize=1024*1024;

struct Foo
{
   int data[dataSize];
};

std::vector<Foo> foo;
std::vector<size_t> fooFree;
std::vector<size_t> fooProcess;
std::mutex dataMutex;

void thread1Func();
void thread2Func();

int main()
{
    foo.resize(10);
    for(size_t i=0;i<10; ++i)
        fooFree.push_back(i);

    std::thread thread1=std::thread(&thread1Func);
    std::thread thread2=std::thread(&thread2Func);

    thread1.join();
    return 0;
}

void thread1Func()
{
    size_t count=0;
    size_t index=std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

    while(true)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(dataMutex);
        
            if(index != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
            {
                fooProcess.push_back(index);
                index=std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
            }

            if(!fooFree.empty())
            {
                index=fooFree.back();
                fooFree.pop_back();
            }
        }
        
        if(index != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
        {
            for(size_t i=0; i<dataSize; ++i)
                foo[index].data[i]=count+i;
            count++;
        }
    }
}

void thread2Func()
{
    size_t index=std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

    while(true)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(dataMutex);

            if(index != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
            {
                fooFree.push_back(index);
                index=std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
            }

            if(!fooProcess.empty())
            {
                index=fooProcess.back();
                fooProcess.pop_back();
            }
        }

        if(index != std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())
        {
            std::cout<<foo[index].data[0]<<"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Prior unlock() operations on the same mutex synchronize-with (as defined in std::memory_order) this operation

Comment: TLDR: _Everything_ that one thread does before it unlocks a mutex will be visible to another thread after the other thread subsequently locks the same mutex.

Comment: Your code looks safe, but highly suboptimal, since your threads are spinning. You should refactor your code to use "condition variables" so that the threads can sleep if there's nothing to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the code. `index` doesn't change value because the code never enters any of the ifs (under or outside locks). That code doesn't do anything, right? It is trivially safe, because no update ever occures. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, 1 sec, fooFree needs some size; just made it compile-able, didn't actually run it (updated code)

Comment: @freakish I believe your OC is correct, in that it is not safe. I think that if the threads end up on separate processors then there is no guarantee that the 2nd processo's cache will be updated and the read could be old. It is a little hazy for me and just looking for someone that might clarify it.

Comment: @Krazer yeah, it is better now. So the code is thread safe, because there are no multiple threads accesing the same memory location at the same time, with at least one of them being a write. But note that you will likely have a performance hit, since your threads access locations very close to each other in parallel. It is likely that data will end up in a single cache line, and hence write propagation will slow down everything (although the cost may be invisible with locks present). In other words, don't read/write data close to each other in multiple threads, in tight loops.

Comment: @Krazer locking and unlocking a mutex acts as a memory barrier. Every update before and/or after it will be visible to other threads. It would be very bad otherwise. Your code is safe.

Comment: A very common pattern is to modify an object, acquire a mutex, tell other threads about the object, release the mutex, then allow other threads to acquire the mutex and find/access the object.